# Vim comment via command, at specific start and endpoint

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a line that looks like this:

```
 - A random sentence.
```

I want to make it like:

```
 - ~~A random sentence.~~
```

What i have come up with so far:

```
:normal 0 2w i~~
```

If i continue the script, im not able to break out of insert mode, so every command i enter hereafter is interpreted as insert. Next in line would be:

```
A i~~
```

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 norm! 02wi~~^[A~~
```

`^[` you press `Ctrl-V Esc`

Answer (score 0):

With [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) you could place the cursor in the `A` letter and type  `ys$~.` in normal mode. Another method is to use substitution:

```
s/A.*/\~\~&\~\~/
```

Answer (score 0):

With the cursor on `A`:

```
c$~~<C-r>"~~<Esc>
```